# Delphi 7 Indy connect with API OpenAI chatGPT

Tags: delphi, indy, openai-api

Can't connect with https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
from Delphi 7 with TidHTTP

I have in the project directory
ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll
they are tested with other projects

and I get an error:
"Error connecting with SSL"

With "Postman"  there are no errors with my token

```
function TAIform.message_send(JSONtext:String):String;
var idhttp1:Tidhttp;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
    EnvStr : TStringStream;
begin

FError:='';
EnvStr := TStringStream.Create(JSONtext);

try

    idhttp1:=Tidhttp.Create(nil);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.create(nil);
    idhttp1.IOHandler:=IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method:=sslvTLSv1_2;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Content-Type: application/json ');
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization: Bearer ' + FAIToken);  //Bearer
    IdHTTP1.Request.SetHeaders;
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType:='application/json';
    IdHTTP1.Request.Accept:='application/json';

    result:=ConvertFromUTF8(idhttp1.Post( FAIlink,EnvStr));  

 except
   on E: Exception do 
   begin
     FError:= 'Error: '+E.Message+#13#10+ConvertFromUTF8(idhttp1.ResponseError);
   end;
 end;

 EnvStr.free;
 IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.free;
 idhttp1.free;

end;
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You are using an extremely old version of Indy, likely v9 (`TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket` was renamed to `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` in Indy v10). [You need to upgrade](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/wiki/Updating-Indy) to the latest Indy version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was easier for me to write a DLL in Delphi 10 with the same code and connect it to a Delphi 7 project, this solved the issue.